# SSL Configuration Issue on Windows Server 2008 IIS7 - IP doesn't resolves correctly to the site

Tags: ssl, iis-7, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

I'm working on ASP.net MVC3 Web application on a dedicated Windows Server 2k8 running IIS7.

I have configured A record correctly on domain to resolve to this server. I have 1 main site and 2 other small application running on same server. I need to add SSL on all of this site.

While trying to add SSL I have to give separate IP address for each site in IIS7. But as soon as I configure it, site stops working.

One more thing, when I enter IP address directly on the web, it should open that site, but it is not resolving the request. I think if it resolves correctly then SSL issue will be solved, but not sure why IP is not resolving correctly and showing not found error.

Comment: how are the ports set up for the sites.  Just as with the IP, each site needs its own port.   If you try to run multiple sites on the same ssl port then they won't work.

Comment: For SSL what ports do you recommend apart from default

Comment: anything in the 44x range.  depending on what is installed, you may run up against an application already using the port.   typically 443 (default) 446 through 449 are good bets.  Even if 444 and 445 aren't already taken best to leave these open IMO.

Comment: @Brian, [those ports are reserved for something that has nothing to do with HTTPS](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml). 8443 tends to be used more commonly as an alternate port. You should also be able to support multiple host names on the same port/IP without SNI if the certificate is valid for all those host names (via wildcard or SAN).

Comment: I have configured it correctly on different post name as suggested by Brian. Still its now working outside the network. Now it seems to be an firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the firewall issue, and of course with different domains/sub domains, you either need different SSL certificate or SSL certificate that support multiple domains/sub domains. And each of them need to be mapped to different IP addresses or at least different port on same IP.